# Cannot find module './data.json'. in Angular

Tags: angular

I added a file `students.json` in the folder `src/app`.

In the file `app.component.ts`, I have an error message

```
Cannot find module './students.json'.
```

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import studentsData from './students.json';
  
interface Student {
    id: Number;
    name: String;
    email: String;
    gender: String;
}
  
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  
  students: Student[] = studentsData;
}
```

We agree that the patch is correct?

The problem is perhaps in the `tsconfig.json` ?

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
  }
}
```

[https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f3v8ee?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I don't think you can import a JSON file... Where did you read that you can do it?

Comment: @Aviad P. Seriouse? Here ?? https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-display-data-from-json-file-in-angularexample.html

Comment: I was serious but I learned something new.

Comment: @Aviad P. : Ah ok , Me also... ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to your tsconfig.json in `compilerOptions` section:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true
    ...
  }
```

See the forked stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1rxfdn?file=tsconfig.json

Comment: Thank you Michael, why it works on Stackblitz but not on Visual Studi even with `"resolveJsonModule": true ` ? You have an idea?

Comment: @christine check this link https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25400 (restart VS Code)